# Understanding TLS version mismatch issue on dev and prod server

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ssl, tls1.2

I am calling a third party RESTful webservice from my application. Everything was working fine until a couple of weeks back i started getting "**Connection Reset**" error for that url. Below is the stacktrace.

```
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:196)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:122)
at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:442)
at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:480)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:927)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1312)
```

So i reached out to the third party api support team and found they had dropped support for TLS1.0 and were supporting only TLS1.2 from now and asked us to upgrade to TLS1.2.

I am using JAVA7 in my prod and dev environment and after some googling found that TLS1.2 is supported in JAVA7 but is not enabled by default(Ref : https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/diagnosing_tls_ssl_and_https). So to fix the SSL exception i was getting in production(added above), i changed my application code to send httpsUrlConnection request using TLS1.2 and the issue got resolved in my prod environment.

What i wanted to understand is that when i tried to reproduce the same issue on my local environment, i did not get any error and i could successfully connect to the web service. So if this issue is due to the java version, this should have replicated on local environment as well as i am having Java7 on local. The third party api endpoint i am connecting to is the same for both my production and development environment.

```
Raghavs-MacBook-Pro:~ root# java -version 
java version "1.7.0_71"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_71-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.71-b01, mixed mode)
```

Am i missing something in understanding the issue? Can someone explain what might be happening?

Thanks

Comment: The simple answer is that your local environment and prod environment run different cipher suites.

Comment: Since both environments have the same java version installed so wouldn't it be correct to assume the cipher suites would be same as well or does it depend on the operating system??

Comment: Are the rest endpoints the same?

Comment: Yes, the rest endpoint is the same in both cases.

Comment: There seem to be discrepencies between the TLS settings enabled between JRE and JDK versions maybe take a look at what system properties are set, like https.protocols

Comment: "*I resolved this by adding SSLSocketFactory for TLS1.2 in HttpsURLConnection in my application code.*" What do you mean by this?

Comment: @Bruno I have updated my question with more details of the issue which i happened to get in production environment and which i have also fixed. What i actually want to know is why that issue didn't occur while i connected to the third party api from my dev environment when both my prod and dev environment have the same JAVA version.

Comment: Did you set the `-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2` system property?

Comment: I don't think i need to set -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2 as i have managed to resolve the issue with TLS incompatibility on my prod server. What i am looking for is why it didn't occur when i connected to the webservice from my local system. :(